# Is "replace" in kubernetes equivalent to 'update'?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to implement a functionality similar to `kubectl apply` using Kazan, a kubernetes client in Elixir, and trying to understand how to perform a rolling update, in specifically the function `replace_namespaced_deployment`.

Having REST as background, where CRUD are the verbs to manipulate resources, Kubernetes' 'replace' sounds to me like an `UPDATE`, so I try to understand:

- Why replace and not update
- Is replace equivalent to update or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Kubernetes API, "Replace" is synonymous with "Update." A you can see from the [OpenAPI specification](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/api/openapi-spec/v3/apis__apps__v1_openapi.json#L9549), the operations like `replaceAppsV1NamespacedDeployment` are indeed mapped to the `PUT` http method.

### "Why replace and not update?"

In RESTful semantics updating is replacement. When you send data with the `PUT` verb, the convention is that you need to provide the full data for the resource and that that representation of the resource will completely replace whatever the previous representation is. The word "replace" is actually in the definition of the `PUT` method ([rfc9110 Section 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-9)):

> Replace all current representations of the target resource with the request content.

### The Semantics of `kubectl apply`

The behavior of `kubectl apply` is more complex than any one of the standard API methods. It creates the resource if it doesn't exist, and patches it if it does, while also applying some heuristics based on the `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` annotation. Patch is essentially a partial update, but there are multiple types of patches which describe the update differently.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

Long answer: There is no "update" command in Kubernetes. If you want to edit any parameters of a resource, you can edit the yaml file, then run:

```
kubectl replace -f FILE
```

Note that some resources will throw an error saying it is not possible to modify. In that case you will need to delete the resource and create it again.

Comment: The question was about the API operations, not about kubectl commands, and I think it is misleading to say "there is no update."